# angular 6 @angular/core/core"' has no exported member 'state'

Tags: angular6

I migrated from angular 5.2 to 6.0.  When I issue the ng serve command, I get the following error:

> ERROR in src/app/mappy/mappy.component.ts(1,36): error TS2305: Module
>   '"C:/NSE911/applicationDev/angular/alo/node_modules/@angular/core/core"'
>   has no exported member 'state'.

I am using: typescript: 2.7.2, angular cli: 6.0.1, Node: 8.11.2, OS: win32 x 64, angular: 6.0.0, rxjs-compat: "^6.1.0",

I removed the node_modules directory and re-created it again (npm install). This did not work.
I will appreciate any ideas (I am kind of new using this technologies).
Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 6):

The import for "trigger, state, transition, animate, style" has changed from **@angular/core** to **@angular/animations**.

For example:

```
import { trigger, state, transition, animate, style } from '@angular/animations';
```

Answer (score 1):

I found out was was the error:
import { Component, Input, OnInit, state } from '@angular/core';
After I remove the 'state' on the above import statement the problem went way.
lmv

Answer (score 1):

The import for state has changed from `@angular/core` to `@angular/animations`

Comment: Where to make this change ?